# memory leak in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I m having leaks at this particular variable:

```
item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

since i m using `@property(nonatomic,retain)` to synthesize the item. It's obvious to have leaks. I tried autorelease:

```
item = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

since I'm storing all the array content in items. The app crashes. I've tried releasing the memory content in dealloc, but there still are leaks. Could you guys help me out?

Answer (score 2):

If you're synthesizing accessors, why aren't you using them?

Change this:

```
item = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

To this:

```
self.item = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Comment: Instead of allocating and autoreleasing, we can also use the convenience method. `self.item = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`

Comment: thanks man totally worked...have one more leak..cud u help me out.."I m using apple reachablility class"... having leak at this particular place..SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, [hostName UTF8String]);

Comment: Simon's right, you should also use the convenience constructors. Fixed.